# Show that the isometries $\phi: M\rightarrow M$ of a surface $M$ form a group

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, isometry

> Show that the isometries $\phi: M\rightarrow M$ of a surface $M$ form a group

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry#Isometry_definition) states: 
The set of bijective isometries from a metric space to itself forms a group with respect to function composition, called the isometry group.

I'm not sure how to show that.

Comment: Do you know what you need to show? Write out the definitions of all the terms involved, if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isometry group of a metric space is the set of all *bijective*(thus have **inverses**) isometries from the metric space onto itself, with the *function composition*(**associativity**) as group operation. Its **identity element** is the identity function.

So we can see that the group laws are all satisfied.